# Forward all messages to other object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

I have next issue: 
I have a decorator for the `NSButtonCell` class, which adds some functionality. As it is a decorator - is's a subclass of `NSButtonCell`. I didn't like to create subclasses, because the same functionality must be dynamically added\removed to some other subclasses of `NSButtonCell`. And, as it is a decorator, I must forward all messages to the decorated  object, because some subclass can have own 'setting', behaviour and etc. Because `NSButtonCell` has many methods, I can't write code to redirect all messages to decorated  object. Please, tell me, how I can redirect all received messages to decorated object?

Comment: Have you looked at `NSProxy`?

Answer (score 5):

Round Peg meet Square Hole.

The reason why you are finding it so hard to do this is because it is an exceedingly non-standard pattern to use for implementing UI.  Method forwarding as implemented by either `forwardInvocation:` or `NSProxy` is useful, but pretty much never used to implement the Decorator pattern in the context of the UI.

While you *could* use a subclass of NSProxy that selective forwards or implements the methods you need, that is a complete waste of code compared to simply creating a subclass.

Just use a subclass and be done with it.

However, only subclass if you really need to.  If the provided NSButtonCell can do all that you need and it is merely a matter of configuring it, then configure it in your controller or in whatever mechanism that you use to layout and present your user interface.

And in your case, it sounds like a central controller or UI configurator is the way to go as that will centralize the functionality into a single spot that can then control multiple (potentially minimal subclasses) instances of the various UI classes.

Answer (score 1):

Using `NSProxy` is the standard approach for creating objects that act as stand-ins for other objects or objects that don’t exist yet. Its entire structure is based around handling methods and forwarding them to the true object.

Comment: But, for example, if I'd like to implement `- (void)drawImage:(NSImage *)image withFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)controlView` in this decorator object? How I should perform drawing?

Comment: The point of the proxy is to forward calls to the real object. When would `drawImage:` be called? I would think more about `drawRect:` being called and setting parameters on the real class or drawing into the current context (valid during `drawRect:` call.

Comment: `DrawImage:` is called automatically when the button is redrawn.